# Adaptive paypal Payment integration to react-native mobile app Facing an issue with mini view

Tags: react-native, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using webView to open the authorisation url https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?&expType=mini&payKey= with payKey page is open when i click on cancel i have not received a cancelUrl in my callback

Is there any way to do this i receive the url of cancel/complete 
because i have received url redirect in desktop view. Is there i have miss to integrate Adoptive payment of paypal.